# Flask error - NameError: name 'DateField' is not defined

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am trying to build the below page using Flask and get the below error:

```
NameError: name 'DateField' is not defined
```

Given below is the python script

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import datetime, date
import warnings
import os
from io import BytesIO



def demo_func(name,start_date,end_date):

db_connection details
dwh_cursor = conn.cursor()  # set DB Cursor

## The Query
dwh_cursor.execute(sql.SQL(
    """SELECT count(bill_id) from sales where name = {} and created_at between {} and {}""").format(
    sql.Literal(name), sql.Literal(start_date), sql.Literal(end_date)))
```

Given below is the view.py code

```
@app.route('/page1', methods=['GET','POST'])
def carrier_scac():
    form = page1Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        start_date = DateField('Start Date', format="%Y-%m-%d",description='This is the start date of the analysis')
        end_date = DateField('End Date', format="%Y-%m-%d",description='This is the end date of the Analysis')
        output = demo_func(name,start_date,end_date)

        return send_file(output, attachment_filename=name + ' '  + ' Details.xlsx',as_attachment=True)

    return render_template('page1.html', form=form)
```

Code for page1.html

```
<form action=""
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          method="POST">
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        <table>
            {{ render_field(form.name, size=50) }}
            {{ render_field(form.start_date, size=20) }}
            {{ render_field(form.end_date, size=20) }}
            {% for subfield in form.tracking_info_field %}
            {% endfor %}

            <tr class="submit">
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="submit">Get the Report!</button>
```

On running page1.html get an error

```
builtins.NameError
NameError: name 'DateField' is not defined
```

Could anyone guide me where am I going wrong in the above code. Thanks

Comment: is the import statement included i.e from wtforms import DateField ?

Comment: @SarthakNegi, yes I do have from wtforms.fields import  DateField . I forgot to include that in my code earlier..

Comment: not sure if it makes a difference, but I import as follows:  wtforms import DateField , not wtforms.fields import DateField. As Sarthak also points out actually.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry figured I had entered the wrong column in views.py. Got that fixed after rectifiying..